# Error when trying to decrypt token using Python Library, created using JAVA Library

Tags: java, python, algorithm, encryption, jwt

Already have the decryption key and signed_key .. Just need to know which library in python is the correct one to decode the JWT token created by this Java algorithm

JWE Encryption: Algorithm: RSA_OAEP, Encryption A128GCM
Token Signature: Algorithm: RS256

decrypt.py file:

```
 from jwcrypto import jwt, jwk

    k = {"n": G_DECRYPTION_KEY, "kty": "RSA", "e":"A128GCM"} #, "alg":"RS256"} # "e":"AQAB"
    print 'k : %s \n'% k

    key = jwk.JWK(**k)
    print 'key : %s \n'% key

    decrypted_key = jwt.JWT(key=key, jwt= g_token)
    print 'decrypted_key : %s \n'% decrypted_key

    signed_key = jwt.JWT(key=key, jwt=decrypted_key.claims)
    print 'signed_key : %s'% signed_key

    signed_key.claims
    print 'signed_key.claims %s
```

'

Error I am getting:

```
decrypted_key = jwt.JWT(key=key, jwt= g_token)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jwcrypto\jwt.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.deserialize(jwt, key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jwcrypto\jwt.py", line 460, in deserialize
    self.token.deserialize(jwt, key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jwcrypto\jwe.py", line 472, in deserialize
    self.decrypt(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jwcrypto\jwe.py", line 399, in decrypt
    'key' + repr(self.decryptlog))
InvalidJWEData: No recipient matched the provided key["Failed: [KeyError('p',)]"]
```

Comment: You should check if `g_token` looks OK.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I made sure that the g_token is valid, and also working when Java decryption is used, only failing when using Python decryption

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **decryption key** is the same as the **encryption key**. And I believe both keys should be an instance of `jwk.JWK` from `jwcrypto` package